# Concatenate fields and Modify value for each field in an XSL into a single Column in a DB

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to concatenate four fields from a feed that have values of "true" in the feed into a single column in my database separated by commas but instead of displaying true for each field, I want to display a long name of my choosing.

The xsl below is my attempt to combine values for the four fields(RNP_PARK,RNP_PARK2,RNP_PARK3,RNP_PARK4) that have four separate fields from a feed mapped to each field in the xml that this xsl is referencing.

Again the goal is to have all four fields concatenated into a single column in the Database but the syntax below is incorrect.  When I try to download the xml I receive the following error...

ERROR -
'when()' is an unknown XSLT function.

If anybody can provide guidance on how to correct this so that I end up with something like "Open, Beware Animals, National, Free"  that would be very much appreciated!

```
<xsl:variable name="RNP_PARKS">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
    when (RNP_PARK='true') then 'Open '',
    when (RNP_PARK2='true') then ', Beware Animals' otherwise '',
    when (RNP_PARK3='true') then ', National' otherwise '',
    when (RNP_PARK4='true') then ',Free ''
  )" />
</xsl:variable>
```

I tried using If and Choose but neither worked either. Choose was not concatenating since it's into a single field with multiple values and for "if" I received the same error.

I was expecting all of the four values from the feed to be concatenated into a single column in the DB and then the value of true if it exists in the feed would be modified to the long value I am defining in the xsl and the four fields would be separated by a comma.

END GOAL: in the database under a column called NP_PARK if all fields mapped in the xml that the xsl is concatenating are "true" then the column would have a value of "Open, Beware Animals, National, Free"

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In XSLT, `choose` and `when` are instructions (elements ), not functions - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose. Please post a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Note also that `xsl:choose` is intended for selecting one of mutually exclusive options. In your example, where each test is independent of others, you should use multiple `xsl:if` instructions (or instances of the `if()` function, if your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher).

Comment: What should the result be when one of the "input fields" is false? Should there still be a comma placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a xsl:foreach construct for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:variable name="map" select="/root/map/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="RNP_PARKS">
      <xsl:for-each select="root/RNP_PARKS/*[starts-with(name(),'RNP_PARK')][text()='true']">
        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$map[name()= name(current())]"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Lets say we have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <map>
    <RNP_PARK>Open</RNP_PARK>
    <RNP_PARK2>Beware Animals</RNP_PARK2>
    <RNP_PARK3>National</RNP_PARK3>
    <RNP_PARK4>Free</RNP_PARK4>
  </map>
  
  <RNP_PARKS>
    <RNP_PARK>false</RNP_PARK> 
    <RNP_PARK2>true</RNP_PARK2> 
    <RNP_PARK3>true</RNP_PARK3> 
    <RNP_PARK4>true</RNP_PARK4> 
  </RNP_PARKS>
</root>
```

The value of your $RNP_PARKS will be `Beware Animals, National, Free`

With all 4 to true , it will be: `Open, Beware Animals, National, Free`